# Writing a function to check if a word is valid

Tags: c++, function, binary-search-tree

I'm working on a binary search tree that reads from a text file, changes word to lowercase, removes punctuation and checks if word if valid then stores into the binary search tree.

Here I've created a function called `isValidWord()` that checks if the word is lowercase, contains any digits, and contains any punctuation. But for some reason, it still allows words that isn't valid to be stored into the binary search tree.

**isValidWord() function**

```
bool BST::isValidWord(string word) {

    for (int i = 0; word.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!isalnum(word[i]))
        {
            if (!isdigit(word[i])) {

                if (!ispunct(word[i])) {

                    if (!isupper(word[i])) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

**BST Insert function**

```
void BST::insert(string word, TreeNode*& root) {
    transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
    for (int i = 0, len = word.size(); i < len; i++) {

        if (ispunct(word[i])) {
            word.erase(i--, 1);
            len = word.size();
        }
    }

    if (isValidWord(word)) {
        if (root == NULL) {
            root = new TreeNode(word);
        }
        else if (root->data == word) {
            root->count++;
        }
        else {
            if (word >= root->data) {
                insert(word, root->right);
            }
            if (word <= root->data) {
                insert(word, root->left);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong that I can't see? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Eventually, the loop accesses `word[word.size()]`, which is a nul character `'\0'`. This character passes all four checks (it's not a letter, not a digit and not punctuation), and the function returns `true`. `return false;` statement can never be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question cries for the usage of a `std::regex`.

The whole "isValidWord" function can be replaced by by a very simple one-liner:

```
if (std::regex_match(word, std::regex("[a-z]+"))) {
```

In the brackets, you can specify all valid characters. For example [a-z] means, all lowercase characters.

Also your lines

```
    for (int i = 0, len = word.size(); i < len; i++) {

        if (ispunct(word[i])) {
            word.erase(i--, 1);
            len = word.size();
        }
    }
```

can simply be replaced by the ultra simple one liner:

```
word = std::regex_replace(word,  std::regex(R"([\.,:])"), "");
```

Put in the brackets whatever you want to erase.

Please consider.

If you have questions, then please ask

Answer (score 0):

I see no break condition in for-loop.

```
for (int i = 0; word.size(); i++)
{
```

It should be replaced to,

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
{
```